# Map data array for a specific object array type

Tags: angular, rxjs

Maybe a easy question, but I couldn't find a example for this.

**This is my HttpClient call**

```
getItems(dataSourceUrl: string, bindKey: string, bindValue: string): Observable<SelectItem[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Array<any>>(dataSourceUrl);
}
```

I want to map the list result to SelectItem[] based on `bindKey` and `bindValue`. How do I do that?

I tried something like this

```
return this.httpClient.get<Array<any>>(dataSourceUrl).pipe(map(x=> { return { label: data.bindKey, value: data.bindValue } }));
```

**Interface**

```
export interface SelectItem {
    label: string;
    value: any;
}
```

**Example of two different api responses**

**1.**

```
{key:'Istanbul', value: 'Test' }
{key:'London', value: 'Test' }
```

`bindKey` will be `key`
`bindValue` will be `value`

**2.**

```
{name:'Istanbul', id: 'Test' }
{name:'Istanbul', id: 'Test' }
```

`bindKey` will be `id`
`bindValue` will be `name`

Comment: I use [typestack/class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) decorators to convert plain objects to class instances and vice versa. I recommend you to have a look at

Comment: Can u show us what is interface of `SelectItem` and what is the API response. In the code shared, Also, I cant see `data` object which you are using as `data.bindKey` . Am i missing something ? Best thing would be to share `API` response and expected response after applying `map`

Comment: @ShashankVivek  the api response can be a list of any type. That's why I want to map it dinamicaly, based on bindKey , bindValue - both of them properties of the items from the list api response  Example of two api responses
 {key:'Istanbul', value: 'Test' }
 
 {name:'Istanbul', id: 'Test' }
 
 
 bindKey  will be: key, id.
 bindValue will be name, value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
getItems(dataSourceUrl: string, bindKey: string, bindValue: string): Observable<SelectItem[]> {
     return this.httpClient.get<SelectItem[]>(dataSourceUrl)
           .pipe(map(x=> this.transformValue(bindKey,bindValue,x)));
}

transformValue(bindKey,bindValue,response):SelectItem[]{
    const newResponse = [];
    response.forEach(data => {
        newResponse.push({
            label: data[bindKey],
            value: data[bindValue]
        })
    })
    return newResponse;
}
```

Comment: Somehow I thought, that .map can do this automagically without a forEach